# How to know when the row is at top of view to fetch more data in UITableView Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a IOS messaging app written in Swift that has a UITableView.
The messages are displayed from oldest on top and most recent at bottom by datetime.

I am working on loading more data when the row index is 0 but I am not able to figure out how it works.

When the user first loads the messageViewController it downloads the messages for that conversation like this:

```
internal func messagesDownloaded(page: MessagePage) {
   //append page.content to messages (content) array
  for index in 0..<page.content.count {
     self.content.insert(page.content[index], at: index)
  }
  self.progressBar.isHidden = true
  self.LOG.info("reload table")
  self.tableView.reloadData()     

  scrollToBottom()     
}
```

Then if the ui is at top or row is 0 (zero) then fetchMore() data with following func:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1) == indexPath.row {
         LOG.info("the top has reached: row: \(indexPath.row)")
         downloadCheck(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

However, the if clause never enters when the 1st row is visible so I know when to fetchMore data.  What is the best way?